# How to use script output as input arguments Linux shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I have two shell script files: "script1.sh" and "script2.sh".
Running "script1.sh" results in echo two strings.(e.g. str1 str2).
I want this "script1.sh" output (str1 and str2) to be used as the input arguments for the 2nd script, "script2.sh".
(i.e. To be equivalent to ./script2.sh str1 str2)

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`./script1.sh | xargs ./script2.sh`.

This will take your output of `./script1.sh` (i.e. `str1 str2`), split it by space and pass it to `./script2.sh` as arguments.